# Cannot get batch macro to work (cmd.exe)?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I've seen [Batch macro not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45917582/batch-macro-not-working) - but it does not address my question.

Basically, I saw:

- [Set output of a command as a variable (with pipes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14952295/set-output-of-a-command-as-a-variable-with-pipes)
- [Assign output of a program to a variable using a MS batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323292/assign-output-of-a-program-to-a-variable-using-a-ms-batch-file/54425285#54425285)

... and I thought, let me try it.

So first, I save this in a `test.bat` file:

```
powershell -command "$proc = Start-Process notepad.exe -passthru ; Write-Output $proc.id"
pause
```

I double-click this `test.bat`, and I get:

```
C:\tmp>powershell -command "$proc = Start-Process notepad.exe -passthru ; Write-Output $proc.id"
10968

C:\tmp>pause
Press any key to continue . . .
```

So, ok, it works.

---

Then I decide to wrap the above code in a "batch macro" - so `test.bat` becomes instead:

```
%$set% TESTPID="powershell -command "$proc = Start-Process notepad.exe -passthru ; Write-Output $proc.id""
echo TESTPID %TESTPID%
pause
```

Now when I double-click this `test.bat`, it does not work, and I get:

```
C:\tmp>TESTPID="powershell -command "$proc = Start-Process notepad.exe -passthru ; Write-Output $proc.id""
'TESTPID' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\tmp>echo TESTPID
TESTPID

C:\tmp>pause
Press any key to continue . . .
```

It's as if the `%$set%` was interpreted as a variable, and as such was taken as empty, and then the rest of the line was executed ...

So, where am I going wrong - and can I get this "batch macro" to work in this case, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, turns out, that was a whole function that I should have copied - I was otherwise persuaded `%$set%` was a special built-in batch command ...

So the complete working code is:

```
@echo off
call :initMacro

%$set% TESTPID="powershell -command "$proc = Start-Process notepad.exe -passthru ; Write-Output $proc.id""
echo TESTPID %TESTPID[0]%
pause

:initMacro
if "!!"=="" (
    echo ERROR: Delayed Expansion must be disabled while defining macros
    (goto) 2>nul
    (goto) 2>nul
)
(set LF=^
%=empty=%
)
(set \n=^^^
%=empty=%
)

set $set=FOR /L %%N in (1 1 2) dO IF %%N==2 ( %\n%
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion                                 %\n%
    for /f "tokens=1,* delims== " %%1 in ("!argv!") do (            %\n%
        endlocal                                                    %\n%
        endlocal                                                    %\n%
        set "%%~1.Len=0"                                            %\n%
        set "%%~1="                                                 %\n%
        if "!!"=="" (                                               %\n%
            %= Used if delayed expansion is enabled =%              %\n%
                setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion                    %\n%
                for /F "delims=" %%O in ('"%%~2 | findstr /N ^^"') do ( %\n%
                if "!!" NEQ "" (                                    %\n%
                    endlocal                                        %\n%
                    )                                               %\n%
                setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion                    %\n%
                set "line=%%O"                                      %\n%
                setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion                     %\n%
                set pathExt=:                                       %\n%
                set path=;                                          %\n%
                set "line=!line:^=^^!"                              %\n%
                set "line=!line:"=q"^""!"                           %\n%
                call set "line=%%line:^!=q""^!%%"                   %\n%
                set "line=!line:q""=^!"                             %\n%
                set "line="!line:*:=!""                             %\n%
                for /F %%C in ("!%%~1.Len!") do (                   %\n%
                    FOR /F "delims=" %%L in ("!line!") Do (         %\n%
                        endlocal                                    %\n%
                        endlocal                                    %\n%
                        set "%%~1[%%C]=%%~L" !                      %\n%
                        if %%C == 0 (                               %\n%
                            set "%%~1=%%~L" !                       %\n%
                        ) ELSE (                                    %\n%
                            set "%%~1=!%%~1!!LF!%%~L" !             %\n%
                        )                                           %\n%
                    )                                               %\n%
                    set /a %%~1.Len+=1                              %\n%
                )                                                   %\n%
            )                                                       %\n%
        ) ELSE (                                                    %\n%
            %= Used if delayed expansion is disabled =%             %\n%
            for /F "delims=" %%O in ('"%%~2 | findstr /N ^^"') do ( %\n%
                setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion                    %\n%
                set "line=%%O"                                      %\n%
                setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion                     %\n%
                set "line="!line:*:=!""                             %\n%
                for /F %%C in ("!%%~1.Len!") DO (                   %\n%
                    FOR /F "delims=" %%L in ("!line!") DO (         %\n%
                        endlocal                                    %\n%
                        endlocal                                    %\n%
                        set "%%~1[%%C]=%%~L"                        %\n%
                    )                                               %\n%
                    set /a %%~1.Len+=1                              %\n%
                )                                                   %\n%
            )                                                       %\n%
        )                                                           %\n%
        set /a %%~1.Max=%%~1.Len-1                                  %\n%
)                                                                   %\n%
    ) else setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion^&set argv=
```

When I double-click the .bat file now, I get:

```
TESTPID 17704
Press any key to continue . . .
```

... which is what I expected ...